# Replacing 'match' object with string, Python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I want to replace certain lines in my text with another string. So far I was able to locate the text I want to replace with:

```
text = open('sample','r').read()
regex = re.compile('.*#= min, max\s')
for match in regex.finditer(text):
    print match.group(0) #this is what i want to replace
```

EDIT: also tried

```
text = open('sample','r').read().split('\n')
for line in text:
    line = re.sub('.*#= min, max\s', "HOLA", line)
```

The text stays the same. Could it be that my regex is messed up? I used the same one somewhere else and there was no problem. Also its a simple regex.

How do I switch it to another line? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you're looking for re.sub. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: To your edit: Of course the `text` stays the same. You iterate it over and modify the variable `line`, but drop its contents immediately. Try `newtext=[re.sub('.*#= min, max\s', "HOLA", line)
 for line in text]`.

Comment: If you liked one of these answers, can you accept one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
subbedlines = []

with open('sample','r') as textreader:
    lines = textreader.read().split('\n')

for line in lines:
    subbedlines.append(re.sub('.*#= min, max\s', "HOLA", line))
```

should work if your regex is correct and your lines in the text file are matching.
to write the file again simply do:

```
with open('sample','w') as textwriter:
    for line in subbedlines:
        textwriter.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand what you want. But the `regex` objects's [`sub()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) can be called with either the text you want to replace with, such as

```
regex.sub("new text", text)
```

or with a function taking a match object and returning the text to be replaced with, such as

```
def reverse(match):
    return match.group(0)[-1::-1]
    # or do whatever else you might want to do
regex.sub(reverse, text)
```

so that you are completely free to decide what to replace with.

Be aware that due to the greedy `.*` in your regex, this might replace only the last part. Be sure to work with `$` (end of line), `^` (start of line), `.*?` (non-greedy version) and perhaps the `re` option `MULTILINE`.

Comment: As you can see I tried it (just edited my question), but it doesn't work and I don't know why\

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i dont understand, but why are you iterating line after line, instead of just replacing every it like this:

```
import re

with open("text.txt") as text:
    new_text = re.sub("jj", "xx", text.read())
    with open("newtext.txt", "w") as result:
        result.write(new_text)
```

but maybe I am missing something.